# Missing fastcgi_params

Tags: php, nginx, flarum

I'm using NGINX from `nginx-extras` and Ajenti V with `ajenti-v-nginx` and `ajenti-v`. I have PHP 5.6 installed. However when I execute this code from Flarum Installation:

```
location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY ""; # Fix for https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerability
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

And do a NGINX config check: `sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t` I get

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/conf.d/flarum.conf:39
```

Output of `ls /etc/nginx/`

```
conf.d  fcgi.conf  mime.conf  nginx.conf  proxy.conf
```

Edit1: Seems like it's AjentiV, I reinstalled NGINX and somehow the configs deleted itself

```
root@notascam:/etc/nginx# ls
conf.d        fastcgi_params  koi-win     nginx.conf    scgi_params      
sites-enabled  uwsgi_params
fastcgi.conf  koi-utf         mime.types  proxy_params  sites-available  
snippets       win-utf
root@notascam:/etc/nginx# sudo service nginx start
root@notascam:/etc/nginx# ls
conf.d        fastcgi_params  koi-win     nginx.conf    scgi_params      
sites-enabled  uwsgi_params
fastcgi.conf  koi-utf         mime.types  proxy_params  sites-available  
snippets       win-utf
```

==== Clicks the Restart Website button on Ajenti V ====

```
root@notascam:/etc# cd nginx
root@notascam:/etc/nginx# ls
conf.d  fcgi.conf  mime.conf  nginx.conf  proxy.conf
```

Comment: The error message literally tells you what the problem is.

Comment: @Narf missing file? If I put the file there it deletes itself.

Comment: A file can't delete itself ... Something must delete it, but that has nothing to do with your configuration.

Comment: Didn't solve it. I have myBB in port 80.

Comment: myBB doesn't open network ports, and ports have nothing to do with this to begin with. It seems that you have a hard time describing your issue in the first place ... Try harder.

Comment: Try changing `include fastcgi_params;` to `include fcgi.conf`;

Comment: @TarunLalwani That worked! However, the site is still broken. But that's for another question though. You should make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every nginx setup is different. In your case there is no `fastcgi_params` files, instead there is `fcgi.conf`

So change below

```
include fastcgi_params;
```

to

```
include fcgi.conf;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must find the `fastcgi_params` file, and write the absolute path of it; to find it, run the following

```
sudo find / -name "fastcgi_params"
```

It's usually **`/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`** in Debian-based distros.

> For example on debian and ubuntu by default there is `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` file that should look like this:

- [Nginx Documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi)